# extension error when using function>redirect

Tags: extension

```
$this->EE->functions->redirect('account/not-found');
```

When this is triggered in my extension, I get this error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: stdClassàK´cðËÛ::$flashdata

Filename: libraries/Functions.php

Line Number: 381
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Users/Chad/Repositories/hhc/site/system/codeigniter/system/core/Exceptions.php:170)

Filename: libraries/Functions.php

Line Number: 414
```

I am not using flashdata, don't care about it. Any reason this error is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that strange encoding actually displaying on the stdClass undefined property?

Which hook are you using to call the extension? Something may not be setup on the object yet...

Just out of curiousity, did you try ee()->functions->redirect('account/not-found');

Comment: Or you can just use standard PHP: 

`header('location: /account/not-found');
exit();`

Comment: David I went with this basic PHP suggestion. No real time to waste on this project so I'll go with that and not worry about the cause right now.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't get that to work consider using [Codeigniter's URL Helper](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html). See `redirect()` at bottom of page.

For example:

```
public function sessions_end()
{
   $this->EE->load->helper('url');
   redirect('/account/not-found/');
}
```